# Keyboard ADJUST_RESIZE is not working in DialogFragment in Android 8 or above and Notch devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, window-soft-input-mode

I've implemented a DialogFragment that is shown from an Acivity with '`windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`' but inside the DialogFragment I've used ADJUST_RESIZE input mode:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
```

But it is working fine in Note 5 (Android 7.0) devices but not in Notch devices  Note 8 (Android 9.0) or Huawei Y9 (8.0). Is this issue version related or Notch has to do something with it. How can i resolve this issue. Any ideas would be appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: unfortunately no! So, I had to sue transparent activity to behave like a Dialog in that case